# Nlog Logrotation, keep 7 days of logfiles than archive it every sunday

Tags: c#, logging, nlog, logrotate, log-rotation

Is there a way to create a log rotation with NLOG that records a log for each day for seven days and then archives them after the seven days?

this is my current target with this i :

```
<target xsi:type="File"
            name="error"
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}}: - ${message}"
            fileName="${basedir}/logs/Error.log"
            archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/archive/Error{#}.zip"
            archiveNumbering="Rolling"
            enableArchiveFileCompression="true"
            archiveEvery="Sunday"
            archiveAboveSize="10000000"
            maxArchiveDays ="28"
            archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
            concurrentWrites="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

NLog likes to have single static file, but maybe this is possible:

```xml
<target xsi:type="File"
            name="error"
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}}: - ${message}"
            fileName="${basedir}/logs/Error.${date:format=ddd}.log"
            archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/archive/Error.{#}.zip"
            archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
            archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"
            archiveEvery="Day"
            enableArchiveFileCompression="true"
            archiveAboveSize="10000000"
            maxArchiveDays ="28"
            concurrentWrites="false"/>
```

Then `${basedir}/logs/`-folder will grow to have 7 files:

- Error.Mon.log
- Error.Tue.log
- Error.Wed.log
- Error.Thu.log
- Error.Fri.log
- Error.Sat.log
- Error.Sun.log

And when "rolling" to next file that already exists (ex. `Error.Mon.log`), then the old file will be moved to `${basedir}/logs/archive/`-folder and renamed to `Error.yyyy-MM-dd.log` (Using timestamp of when the old file was created)

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/FileTarget-Archive-Examples